# Creation of Excel sheet function

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that iterates through my folder for file names and then adds to the dictionary.

If file name does not exist, then "do something" (add filename into Excel sheet) else "do nothing".

However when filename exists, the "do nothing" part will wipe out the filenames in the Excel sheet and leave the sheet blank.

I know that it is due to these lines

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = CreateOutputSheet(ActiveWorkbook)
```

How can I change the function code or main code so when dictionary exists, it will do nothing to the data in the sheet. I must keep the sheet name as "Data".

```
Public Dict As Object 
Sub Test1()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object

If Dict Is Nothing Then
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dict.Add Key:="filename", Item:=oFile
End If

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Dekstop\")

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = CreateOutputSheet(ActiveWorkbook)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If Not Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then
    ' Do something 

    Else 
    ' Do nothing 

    End If 
Next oFile
End Sub 


Private Function CreateOutputSheet(ByVal book As Workbook) As Worksheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wks.Name = "Data" Then
        wks.Delete
    End If
    Next wks
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set wks = book.Worksheets.Add(After:=book.Worksheets(book.Worksheets.count))
    wks.Name = "Data"
    AddColumnHeaders wks
    Set CreateOutputSheet = wks
End Function
```

Comment: `For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` should be `For Each wks In book.Worksheets`  However, it's difficult to see how that function is related to the problem you describe ("it will wipe out the filenames in the excel sheet and leave the sheet blank") since there's no code included in the "if doesn't exist in Dict" part of your post.  If the `Else` part really is "do nothing" then you don't even need that part of the `If` block

Comment: @TimWilliams its because the function deletes my sheet everytime before the data gets extracted into it, meaning the previous data of e.g 60 files on my sheet will be cleared out before adding the e.g 2 new file data thus leaving me with only the 2 files in the excel sheet, however if i were to remove the `wks.Delete` line from the function then it would have an error `That name is already Taken` im really sorry once again if i was not clear with my question :(

Comment: @mzmz Do you understand that a dictionary object does not persist, it is destroyed when the workbook is closed. Next time you open the workbook you are creating a new blank dictionary. I think before you scan the selected folder for new files you need to scan your data sheet (which has entries from previous runs) and insert dictionary entries for them. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Comment: If you don't want to recreate the sheet every time you run your code, then why are you doing that?  It's your code - you are the one who controls what it does.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm beginning to understand what you are trying to do. My verdict is that you wouldn't need a dictionary if I understand you correctly and fully. The code below writes the dictionary but doesn't need it to determine what to write to the worksheet. In the end, the dictionary contains a list of the file names with the file objects as `Items` while the worksheet just has the file names. You can delete all references to the dictionary without affecting the remaining functionality of the code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Dict As Scripting.Dictionary         ' prefer early binding

Sub Test1()

    ' early binding works faster and gives you Intellisense access.
    ' use late binding only if your program will run on different versions of Excel
    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject            ' prefer early binding
    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oFile As File
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fn As String                        ' Base file name
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long

    If Dict Is Nothing Then
        Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\")
    Set Ws = CreateOutputSheet(ActiveWorkbook)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Fn = oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)
        With Ws
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        R = Application.Match(Fn, Rng, 0)
        ' write to worksheet
        If Err Then Rng.Cells(Rng.Cells.Count + 1).Value = Fn

        ' write to dictionary
        If Not Dict.Exists(Fn) Then
            Dict.Add Key:=Fn, Item:=oFile
        End If
    Next oFile
End Sub

Private Function CreateOutputSheet(ByVal Wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    With Wb.Worksheets
        Set Ws = .Item("Data")
        If Err Then
            Set Ws = .Add(After:=.Item(.Count))
            Ws.Name = "Data"
        End If
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
'    AddColumnHeaders Ws
    Ws.Cells(1, "A").Value = "FileNames"        ' remove
    Set CreateOutputSheet = Ws
End Function
```

The part I still don't understand is how you would ever find a file that's already in the list, since you delete the list on every run and start a new one. Perhaps your intention is to change that. Let me know if you need help to find your way through my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed and commented your code. Here it is. It works just fine.

```
Option Explicit

Public Dict As Scripting.Dictionary         ' prefer early binding

Sub Test1()

    ' early binding works faster and gives you Intellisense access.
    ' use late binding only if your program will run on different versions of Excel
    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject            ' prefer early binding
    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oFile As File
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    If Dict Is Nothing Then
        ' Here you are creating a dictionary with one item in it
        ' Key = "Filename", Item = an empty object
        ' no further items are added in this code
        Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Dict.Add Key:="filename", Item:=oFile
    End If

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\")
    Set Ws = CreateOutputSheet(ActiveWorkbook)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Debug.Print "GetBaseName = "; oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)
        ' oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile) returns a string holding the name
        ' of the file indicated by the argument
        ' (without path and without extension)
        ' The argument must be a path, i.e. a string, not a file object (!)
        ' If the item wasn't found a nulstring is returned
        ' apparently oFile's default property is its Name.
        ' Therefore your call here actually works.

        Debug.Print Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile))
        ' This call returns False for every call because the dictionary is empty.


        If Not Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then
            ' this condition is never met for reasons stated above.
            Debug.Print "Do something"

        End If
    Next oFile
End Sub

Private Function CreateOutputSheet(ByVal Wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Ws.Name = "Data" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next Ws

    With Wb.Worksheets
        Set Ws = .Add(After:=.Item(.Count))
    End With
    Ws.Name = "Data"

    AddColumnHeaders Ws
    Set CreateOutputSheet = Ws
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much for the code, but somehow it's still generating the same problem... it's still left with a blank page everytime dictionary exists, if you can have a look at my above comment regarding the issue would be great, thank you... sorry for wasting your effort because i didn't explain well enough